# Ubuntu Touch Apps don't recognize Ubuntu MultiTouch, utouch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was under the assumption that the Ubuntu Touch Apps as found [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/07/join-the-ubuntu-touch-core-apps-development-team/) would run using the Ubuntu Touch stack, supporting gestures and touch events. However through my attempts I have only been able to get these apps to run using the mouse and there doesn't seem to be any gesture support.

My Touch Table hardware is producing touch events conforming to the [MultiTouch protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt) and has been tested and works fine with Kivy's TouchTracer app, used to test various inputs.

I am not sure why the Ubuntu Touch mobile apps wouldn't work with uTouch, I haven't be able to find any information regarding this and what touch stack Ubuntu Touch is using.

Put short, why don't Ubuntu Touch apps support the MultiTouch Protocol? And how can I develop apps that make use of the MultiTouch protocol? (the `ABS_MT_POSITION_X` and `ABS_MY_POSITION_Y` input events going through evdev).

Answer (score 1):

You should never have been able to use the [evdev multitouch protocol](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt), at least in production, because the evdev devices are typically readable only by root. X11 apps used the XI 2.x protocol for their multitouch support.

As far as I know, Mir (the display server library that Ubuntu Touch uses) forwards all the appropriate touch events on to the clients, but my detailed knowledge of the stack ends there.

I'm pretty sure Qt5 has multitouch support, and that's presumably how apps are expected to get multitouch events. Are those events not getting through?

Answer (score 0):

> Put short, why don't Ubuntu Touch apps support the MultiTouch Protocol? And how can I develop apps that make use of the MultiTouch protocol?

This is a planned feature. If it doesn't work quite right is because it's a developer preview, not a finished product. You must expect certain quirks in the development of the device.

I would give the developers time to iron out bugs and other issues before trying to use not-quite-yet-developed-features.